# WordPress login page not found using IIS web server

Tags: wordpress, iis

The front-end of my WordPress website on IIS server is working fine, but when I attempt to login it shows a HTTP 404 error.

My site link http://www.bermits.com/wp-admin is redirected to http://www.bermits.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bermits.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
and shows a 404 error.

Comment: can you post htaccess code?

Answer (score 0):

your system.webServer code like this

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: i am not using .htaccess whereas i am using web.config for iis.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182602/root-url-shows-404-file-or-directory-not-found